# How do I clear an embeds data? | Discord.JS

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I am currently attempting to make a discord bot that displays an 'order' through embed to a channel upon using a certain command !job . The arguments are also the fields in the embed. Then the user has to type 'accept' to accept said job. This then deletes the first embed it posted and then posts a new one stating 'order is closed' so that order can no longer be 'accepted' by anyone else.

Problem: The first embed works fine consistently after the bot has been restarted; however, the 'order is closed' embed posts all the previous embeds recorded. E.g. If the first job states 'x', the embed only outputs that order like it's supposed to. However if a second job is recorded 'y', both will be output and stack up. On the third order it outputs all 3 recorded etc.

After the !job  is used:

[image: image1]

After 'accept' is entered, to accept the job:
[image: image2]

After the second job is placed, and accepted, both orders are output:
[image: image3]

Relevant code:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
 console.log(`Starting up. Running version ${version}`)
});


function isCommand(command, message) {
 var command = command.toLowerCase(); //If a user types a command with uppercase either lowercase
 var content = message.content.toLowerCase()
 return content.startsWith(prefix + command); //Checking if the message has a prefix first.
};
//isNotCommand function (needed
client.on('message', (message) => {

   if (isCommand('job', message)) {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

    // Checking if they have perms
    if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Owner")) {
     const boostEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('GREEN')
      .setDescription("A job has just been placed. Details are below.")
      .setAuthor(' Job Placed!')
      .addField("Rank", args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5], true)
      .addField("Queue", args[6], true)
      .addField("Console", args[7], true)
      .addField("Payout", args[8], true)

     const closedEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RED')
      .setDescription("~~A job has just been placed. Details are below.~~")
      .setAuthor(' Job Closed!')
      .addField("Rank", "~~" + args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5] + "~~", true)
      .addField("Queue", "~~" + args[6] + "~~", true)
      .addField("Console", "~~" + args[7] + "~~", true)
      .addField("Payout", "~~" + args[8] + "~~", true)

     const messagingEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('GREEN')
      .setDescription("You have accepted the job. Details are below.")
      .setAuthor(' Job Accepted!')
      .addField("Rank", args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5], true)
      .addField("Payout", args[8], true)
      .addField("Username", args[9], true)
      .addField("Password", args[10], true)



     if (args[1] === undefined) {
      message.author.send("!job <Rank> <Queue | Single / Duo> <Console> <Payout> <Username> <Password>")
       .then(function(message) {
        setTimeout(function() {
         message.delete();
        }, 10000);
       })
     } else { // Main
      message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelidrequest).send(boostEmbed)
      message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelidrequest).send("React if you want to take the job!")
       .then(function(message) {
        message.react("✅")
       })

      const filter = m => m.content.includes('accept');
      const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
       time: 172800000
      });

      collector.on('end', collected => {
       message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelidrequest).bulkDelete(1);
       const msg = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelidrequest).fetchMessages({
        limit: 1
       })
       msg.edit(closedEmbed);
      })

      console.log(collector)
      collector.on('collect', message => {
         if (message.content == "accept") {
          message.channel.send("Hello");
         }
         const user = message.author
         if (user.id === "722188709612748830") {
          console.log("No Bots");
         } else {
          message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelidrequest).bulkDelete(2);

          message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelidrequest).send(closedEmbed);

          const joblogEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setColor('YELLOW')
           .setDescription("A job has just been logged. Details are below.")
           .setAuthor(' Job Logged!')
           .addField("Rank", args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5], true)
           .addField("Queue", args[6], true)
           .addField("Console", args[7], true)
           .addField("Payout", args[8], true)
           .addField("Username", args[9], true)
           .addField("Password", args[10], true)
           .addField("Booster", "<@" + user.id + ">", true)
          message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelidlog).send(joblogEmbed)
          user.send(messagingEmbed);

         }
```

Long story short the outputs stack on top of each other, when I simply only want it to display the 'order closed' embed relevant to the order placed. Apologies if there's any confusion this is my first post.

Answer (score -1):

The same phenomenon happened to me.
However, when I restarted the server, it was cured.